# Cannot display images in browser Mozilla Firefox, Chrome

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have the code in my Helper.cs like below:

```
public static string NoImagePath { get { return "file:///W:/images/noimage.png"; } }
```

In the view :

```
<% if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Item[i].PictureName)){ %>
<img width="135px" height="100px" src="<%: HelperClass.CheckImageUrlExist(Model.Item[i].PictureName)%>" alt="<%: Model.Item[i].Name %>" /> 
<%}else{ %>
<img width="135px" height="100px" src="<%:HelperClass.NoImagePath %>" alt="No Image"/>           
<%} %>
```

All these images can display only in IE but the other browsers like mozilla firefox, chrome .. cannot. Anyone can solve this issue?

Thank.

Comment: See http://kb.mozillazine.org/Links_to_local_pages_don't_work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a relative path. Most browsers don't support the `file://` URI due to security reasons (Google it, I'm too lazy to link), so if you place your images into a folder and reference them absolutely or relatively, the HTML should render fine in all browsers.

Comment: But all images are store in different server from web server. So how can I include image's path from different server ?

Comment: Use either an absolute URL (`http://www.example.com/image.png`) or a relative URL (`../folder/../image.png`).

Comment: Thanks Blender. But it is in local server.

Comment: No, Blender. It is in a different share folder. I hope everyone can help me. Thanks.

Comment: You're out of luck then, as browser security restrictions are not things you can get around easily.

Comment: If you are using IIS you can map a virtual directory in your site pointing to another path. Let's say your site is in e:\web\mysite. You cna map something to w:\images\. so your site will see that dir like an internal folder to read from